# Magento2 Full Page Cache Automatically Invalidated

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I have running magento243 version and it is working fine .

But I am facing issue in cache flush. My admin cache is automatically cleared after every 30 minutes.

I am using cron scheduler extension and I also disabled all cron from enable status to disable.

And then also  cache clean automatically after  every exact 30 minutes .

does anyone know what could be the problem ?